# How to create a table and make sure the entire row is unique

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table and make sure the entire row is unique,would the following work?

```
ALTER TABLE `gerrits`.`gerrit_submit_table` 
ADD UNIQUE idx_row_unique(`S.No`,`gerrit_id`,`SI`,`component`,`gerrit_owner`,`release_bit`,`picked_bit`);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_row_unique (...)`? [Check the documentation for `ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, that will work. Adding a single unique statement with attributes separated by commas ensures that the entire row is unique, though you can have repeats in the columns.

If on the other hand, you want to make each column unique, you do so with indivdual unique statements.

If you want to specify it with an index name use:

```
ALTER TABLE `gerrits`.`gerrit_submit_table` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_row_unique(`S.No`,`gerrit_id`,`SI`,`component`,`gerrit_owner`,`release_bit`,`picked_bit`);
```

If you don't care what the index name is, it will automatically create one for you using:

```
ALTER TABLE `gerrits`.`gerrit_submit_table` 
ADD UNIQUE(`S.No`,`gerrit_id`,`SI`,`component`,`gerrit_owner`,`release_bit`,`picked_bit`);
```

Comment: should it be `ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_row_unique (...)` or `ADD UNIQUE  idx_row_unique (...)`

Comment: I have updated my answer for you. Not sure if the word INDEX is optional in the first example, you can try leaving it off and see what happens. You will be able to do a `show columns from gerrit_submit_table;` and `show create table gerrit_submit_table\G` to see what the recreation code looks like of both and see if there is a difference. The \G option can be used in place of a semi-colon to display your results in long format.

Answer (score 1):

make all the columns part of the primary key

all of the columns might be extreme though, that could make for a slow table. think it over, maybe you can reduce the unique restriction somehow.

Comment: No. All columns should not be made part of the primary key. If the OP wants to join it to another table using a foreign key that would be ludicrous.

Comment: should it be `ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_row_unique (...)` or `ADD UNIQUE  idx_row_unique (...)`